# How can I ensure the destination file does not exist when renaming a file with Haskell, to avoid overwriting it?

Tags: haskell

I want to rename a file in Haskell without overwriting an already existing one. In case the target file exists I want to deal with that in my code (by appending something to the file name).

The description of [`renameFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.0.0/docs/System-Directory.html) from `System.Directory` says:

> `renameFile old new` changes the name of an existing file system object from `old` to `new`. If the `new` object already exists, it is atomically replaced by the `old` object. Neither path may refer to an existing directory.

Is there any existing module or command that would let me rename without overwriting?

I know I can do the checks myself. I'd just feel *much* better if there was a function written by someone experienced. Overwritten files are gone for good.

**Update**

I want to rename photos, videos, live photos by creation data from either EXIF (similar to `jhead`) or the file system timestamp normalized to the timezone the photo was taken in. It might be that two photos were taken at exactly the same time and would end up with the same name: `2017-01-12 – 11-12-11.jpg`. This *must* not happen. The second photo should be called something like `2017-01-12 – 11-12-11a.jpg`.

Comment: The problem with checking first is that between the check and the actual rename some other process may have created the target file. This is a classic race condition. I don't think it's fixable.

Comment: How are other programs dealing with this? `jhead` renames image files and adds letters to a file name to prevent overwriting existing files. Or do you think that they have the same problem and just consider it unlikely that a new file is created or another one is rename in the time between check and renaming?

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb. It can be done safely by using `link`/`unlink` instead of `rename`. `link(oldname, newname)` will fail if `newname` already exists. In Haskell, these would be [`createLink` and `removeLink`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#g:8), respectively.

Comment: @melpomene: That assumes that you're linking/unlinking a file in the same directory -- if you want to be more precise, linking and unlinking on the same file system. This is generally the case, but you have to be careful if you cross directory boundaries because directories are mount points, and you could inadvertently cross file systems. That would cause link and unlink to fail.

Comment: @scootermefecit `renameFile` has the same limitation.

Comment: @melpomene: Just a cautionary note about using link/unlink, nothing more. Doesn't really solve the problem of the OP, tho.

Comment: @melpomene I guess the generic non-POSIX `renameFile` can not assume to have a safe way to do that provided by the OS. :-/

Comment: @Dominik: I think you need to restate your question with more clarity of purpose: When you attempt to rename a file, are you trying to generate alternate file names in the event the original target file name exists? Or just ensure that the target doesn't exist before you rename?

Comment: I want to rename photos, videos, live photos by creation data from either EXIF (similar to `jhead`) or the file system timestamp normalized to the timezone the photo was taken in. It might be that two photos were taken at exactly the same time and would end up with the same name: `2017-01-12 – 11-12-11.jpg`. This must not happen. The second photo should be called something like `2017-01-12 – 11-12-11a.jpg`. Does that make it clearer? Which other information do you need? If this helps I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @melpomene: It's perhaps a defect in base's file creation functions: you can eliminate the operating system's potential file creation race condition if you could specify O_EXCL when creating it. Might be an enhancement to propose, e.g., createFileExclusively (or some such.)

Comment: @Dominik: Ok, you just want to ensure the target file doesn't exist before you rename. IIRC, you have to see if the file exists before you rename.

Comment: Yes. I want to make sure that I'm not overwriting an existing picture. This _must_ not happen.

Comment: @melpomene: The `stdio` library actually uses `link` and `unlink` as the implementation for `rename`, hence, the same limitation issue.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX has the ability to *create a new file*: atomically check a file exists and only create it if it does not, via the `O_EXCL` flag to [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). This lets you avoid the race condition in the more obvious implementation in which two processes may check that a file doesn't exist before either of them creates it, causing one process to overwrite the other's file. This can help here: the idea is to exclusively create an empty file at the target, and then overwrite it with a rename only if the exclusive creation succeeded. If the exclusive creation failed then another process already created the file. This is exposed in Haskell's [`unix` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/), via the [`openFd` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-IO.html#v:openFd), which either succeeds or else throws an `IOException`. It can be used like this:

```
module RenameNoOverwrite where

import           Control.Exception
import           Control.Monad
import           Data.Bits
import           System.Directory
import           System.Posix.Files
import           System.Posix.IO

renameFileNoOverwrite :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO Bool
renameFileNoOverwrite old new = do
  created <- handle handleIOException $ bracket createNewFile closeFd $ pure $ pure True
  when created $ renameFile old new
  return created

  where
  createNewFile = openFd new WriteOnly (Just defaultMode) defaultFileFlags {exclusive = True}
  defaultMode = ownerReadMode  .|. ownerWriteMode .|. groupReadMode  .|. otherReadMode

  handleIOException :: IOException -> IO Bool
  handleIOException _ = return False
```

The key part is the `{exclusive = True}` option, which sets the `O_EXCL` flag on the resulting call to `open()`.

Windows has a similar ability, exposed via the `CREATE_NEW` flag to [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). There's also a `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING` flag to [`MoveFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) that looks like it might be useful, but I've never used it and the documentation is not 100% clear to me. These are exposed in Haskell's [`Win32` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.8.0.0).

Unfortunately there doesn't currently seem to be a portable way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one potential solution:

```
import System.Directory (doesFileExist, renameFile)

-- | Rename a src file as tgt file, safely. If the tgt file exists, don't
-- rename and return False. Otherwise, rename src to tgt and return True.
renameSafely :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO Bool
renameSafely src tgt = do
  exists <- doesFileExist tgt
  if not exists
  then (renameFile src tgt >> return True)
  else return False
```

(Disclaimer: I didn't run this through GHC to ensure that it compiles; the ">>" in the `then` clause might be an issue.)

As noted in the comments, there is a potential race condition in the file system with two processes trying to create or rename a file with the same name at the same time. However, as you pointed out, that is unlikely to be an issue for you.

If `renameSafely` returns `IO False`, then simply try another name. :-)

Comment: So if I would want to add something to the file name I'd remove the Boolean return value and either recursively call the function or check different paths `2017-01-11 - 11-21-21a.jpg`, `2017-01-11 - 11-21-21b.jpg`, … and rename then. Korrekt? Or would you do that from another function?

Comment: @Dominik Both approaches seem OK to me. You can also write a `genFreshName :: String -> IO String` which returns an unused filename, possibly adding a trailer, and after using the regular rename. (The same race is still here, obviously)

Comment: If I iterate over a list of paths in Haskell there will be no race condition inside my script, right? So Haskell will not try to parallelize the work and rename in different processes. The only race condition here is from the outside world. Some other program might work on the files at the same time.

Comment: @Dominik: The complete solution is a combination of `renameSafely` and `genFreshName`.

You are correct about the O/S race condition: it will only manifest itself if there are competing (external) processes trying to create the same file.

Comment: @Dominik: There's another way to do it, although I don't have time this afternoon to code it up and test: You could use `takeWhileM` as a way to filter out existing file names (i.e., the predicate returns `False` if the file exists, `True` if it doesn't exist) -- `takeWhileM` drops all of the generated names in a list, the head of the returned list is the first name of a legitimate (non-existent) file. Then you use that name to rename the source file.